# Generate random characters by clicking button and safe result to database

Tags: php, mysql, character

I need a simple method without JavaScript (if possible), to generate random characters (the number of characters needs to be set by dropdown-menu), including every UTF-8 character by clicking a button. The result needs to be showen on my site after clicking the button and it should send the result into my database.

Comment: I did not even know how to start, so I asked to get some ideas of how it could work. I see your answer. How do I send the results to the database and how do I create the button? Are there any examples out there? I am searching for a while, but maybe I am using the wrong keywords.

Comment: Now if you are building a random password generator you should not store the data anywhere. Well you can use basic INSERT INTO query, and with PHP I suggest you take a look at PDO, there are many PHP PDO tutorials online. And you are looking for basic html form I'm sure there everything you need to know online.

Comment: I found this here. http://jsfiddle.net/a2r9k/
I am not using this for public. The function to save every result after clicking the button into database is needed for later research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Form**

```
<form method="post">
    Password length: <input type="text" name="length" value="12" />
    <button type="submit" name="generate">Generate</button>
</form>
```

**PHP function to generate password**

```
function getRandomPassword($length=12, $chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZ0123456789!@#$%^&*()_-=+;:,.?"){
    return substr(str_shuffle($chars),0,$length);
}
```

**PHP Save password to database**

```
function savePasswordToDatabase($password, $dbh){
  // First we prepare our query
  $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO tablenamehere (`fieldnamehere`) VALUES (:password)");

  // We bind values to our prepared query
  $stmt->bindParam(':password',$password);

  // We execute our query
  $stmt->execute();
}
```

**Connect to db** I put this here, so you can use the same connection for multiple queries

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=HOST_HERE;dbname=DATABASENAME_HERE', 'USERNAME_HERE', 'PASSWORD_HERE');
```

**PHP Catch form submit**

```
if (isset($_POST['generate'])) {
    $length = (int)$_POST['length'];
    if ($length < 6) $length = 6;
    $randomPassword = getRandomPassword($length);
    savePasswordToDatabase($randomPassword, $dbh);
    echo "Password is: {$randomPassword}";
}
```

**Basicly the end result combined**

```
<?php

function getRandomPassword($length=12, $chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZ0123456789!@#$%^&*()_-=+;:,.?"){
    return substr(str_shuffle($chars),0,$length);
}

function savePasswordToDatabase($password, $dbh){
  // First we prepare our query
  $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO tablenamehere (`fieldnamehere`) VALUES (:password)");

  // We bind values to our prepared query
  $stmt->bindParam(':password',$password);

  // We execute our query
  $stmt->execute();
}

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=HOST_HERE;dbname=DATABASENAME_HERE', 'USERNAME_HERE', 'PASSWORD_HERE');
?>
<html>
<body>
    <form method="post">
        Password length: <input type="text" name="length" value="12" />
        <button type="submit" name="generate">Generate</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

<?php 
if (isset($_POST['generate'])) {
    $length = (int)$_POST['length'];
    if ($length < 6) $length = 6;
    $randomPassword = getRandomPassword($length);
    savePasswordToDatabase($randomPassword, $dbh);
    echo "Password is: {$randomPassword}";
}
?>
```